# Trigger a Formula-based Conditional Format

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements, formula

I have set up a formula-based conditional format that depends on a value that is selected from a dropdown menu (combobox) on the page. The problem is that, after a dropdown selection is made, the format is not applied immediately, rather, I have to scroll the page to hide the affected cells, then scroll back to see the conditional format enabled.

How can I trigger the conditional format when the dropdown selection is made, without having to scroll the page?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug in Excel (at least some versions).  Have a look at this link to see if any of these fixes will work for you.
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/382099-conditional-formatting-does-not-refresh.html

Comment: Thank you. One of the suggestions in that thread solved the problem: In the Developer tab, Visual Basic > View > Properties WIndow:  set EnableFormatConditionsCalculation to True.